# Solve a certain optimization problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am new user of Mathematica. I want to solve an optimization problem.

```
W = (n (X-Y-Z) p / Z q)^(1/a)
```

where

```
a > 0
```

I want the maximum of `W` subject to

```
0 <= n <= 1;
0 <= Y <= X;
Z <= Z_max
```

What is the values of `n` and `Y` that maximize `W`?

Comment: Have you seen `Maximize[]`?

Comment: yes see, but not working                                                                            W = ((n (X - Y - Z) p)/(Z q));
Maximize[{W, 0 \GreaterEqual n \GreaterEqual 1, 
  0 \GreaterEqual  Y \GreaterEqual X}]

Comment: Did you look at the help file for this? In particular, did you notice that `Maximize[]` needs a second argument?